# Unexpected use of reserved word 'class' No stack

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

[image]

I'm trying to run a legacy react native app on my cellphone but I'm getting this strange error. I can't get any details or where on my code this problem exist.

I think it may be on some dependency. I'll put part of my package.json here:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.2.3",
    "axios": "0.18.0",
    "compare-versions": "^3.6.0",
    "d3-geo": "1.11.6",
    "formik": "1.5.1",
    "geolib": "2.0.24",
    "lodash": "4.17.11",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "native-base": "2.12.0",
    "rbush": "^3.0.1",
    "rbush-knn": "^2.1.0",
    "react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.5",
    "react-native-animatable": "1.3.1",
    "react-native-camera": "1.12.0",
    "react-native-config": "1.3.3",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-fs": "2.13.3",
    "react-native-geojson": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "2.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "1.0.16",
    "react-native-head-less-js": "1.0.6",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "0.22.0",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "1.0.1",
    "react-native-keychain": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-maps": "0.25.0",
    "react-native-masked-text": "1.11.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "1.1.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "1.1.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.2.0",
    "react-native-swiper-flatlist": "1.0.10",
    "react-native-version-check": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-zip-archive": "4.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "3.3.0",
    "react-redux": "6.0.1",
    "realm": "2.29.2",
    "redux": "4.0.1",
    "redux-saga": "1.0.1",
    "reduxsauce": "1.0.1",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "0.10.15",
    "seamless-immutable": "7.1.4",
    "styled-components": "4.1.3",
    "supercluster": "4.1.1",
    "unorm": "1.5.0",
    "uuid": "3.3.2",
    "yup": "0.26.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "6.9.4",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.52.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
  }
}
```

It is a legacy project so react native version is 0.58.5 and I'm using node version 10 to run.

Comment: In exactly the same situation as you. Did you ever solve it?

Comment: @Unforgiven, I couldn't solve this problem by any means. I had to recreate the project from scratch and all the dependencies again plus I have fixed the versions of all the dependencies.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that. Thank you.